# My service doesn't stop

Tags: android

Every time my service needs to stop it's just restarting itself. It only stops when I'm forcing it to stop but programmatically it does not stop.

This is my service:

```
public class GpsTracker extends Service  {
    // flag for GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean canGetLocation = false;
        protected LocationManager lm;       
        Location location;// location
        Location sp;
        double latitude; // latitude
        double longitude; // longitude
        double line;
        double ship  ;
        double b   ;
        double[] d = new double[1000];
        String numberr;
        WakeLock wakeLock;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotSleep");
        final LocationListener mlocList = new MyLocationList();
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = lm
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = lm
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            } else {

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        0,
                        0,  mlocList);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (lm != null) {
                    location = lm
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    }
                }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                0,
                                0,  mlocList);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (lm != null) {
                        location = lm
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            }
                    }
                }
            }

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
       // Location mostRecentLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        UpdateWithNewLocation(location); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

     wakeLock.release();
     stopSelf();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


        if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle


            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
             numberr = intent.getStringExtra("number");


            int p=0,j,i=1,t,success=0;


            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([\\d.]+)").matcher(message);

            while(m.find())
            {
               double  k = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
               d[p]=k;
               p++;
               }
          System.out.println(d[0]+d[1]+"THIS IS IT");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Log", "Bundle is null");
        }   
        return START_STICKY;

    }
     private void UpdateWithNewLocation(final Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(loc!= null)
        {
        final double lat =loc.getLatitude(); // Updated lat
        final double Long = loc.getLongitude(); // Updated long

        ship=(d[2]-d[0])/(d[3]-d[1]);
        b=d[0]-ship*d[1];
        line=ship*lat+b-Long; 
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  String.valueOf(lat)+"AND"+String.valueOf(Long), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            System.out.println(b);
            System.out.println(ship);
            System.out.println(line);
           if (line>-1 && line<1){
              SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(numberr, null, "Elvis Just Left The building", null, null);
             onDestroy(); 
        }
        }

        else 
        {
             String latLongStr = "No lat and longitude found";
             Toast.makeText(this, "Your location is "+latLongStr ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }


     public class MyLocationList implements LocationListener
     {

     public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         UpdateWithNewLocation(arg0);
     }

     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS Disable ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }


    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why? I use partial wake lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used START_STICKY. You should use START_NOT_STICKY. Also you should call stopSelf() when you finished your operation! Do not call onDestroy() and from there stopSelf() :-)
Please pause your development for a minute and read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle

> The service will at this point continue running until Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called.

Comment: thanks now it does stop .. but i get a message that saying that the app has stoped... is it possible to stop the service without that message showing ?

Comment: that is probably a crash, an exception... you should run the app with the eclipse debugger or look at the logcat message. there should appear there some backtrace showing what the problem is. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A

Comment: Thanks i just disabled wakelock and now its going smooth.. But somehow the service never get destroyed ( thats my new problem  )